# Java: Replace null values of collection type fields empty collection

Tags: java, json, reflection, java-annotations

Is there a way to parse a nested java object which has multiple collection fields few of them are nulls.

I need something like this

```
@EmptyCollectionIfNull
private List<String> names;
```

Comment: You can do this by creating your own custom annotation and writing an annotation processor.

Comment: looking for something already built

Comment: I don't think you will find one.

Comment: What you're really looking for is Kotlin :)